# Dynamic programming - Getting number of paths in grid from starting point to end point

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I have a matrix, a start point and an end point, and I want to compute a matrix where each matrix[i][j] represents the number of paths from starting point to end point which go by the (i, j) position.

My solution computes the total number of paths from starting point to end point correctly (the value stored in matrix[startx][starty] or matrix[endx][endy]), but not all of the other values are correct.

What do you suggest me?

My code is as follows:

```
private static long solve() {
    board[startx][starty] = 1; 

    for (int i = endx; i <= startx; i++) { 
        for (int j = endy; j >= starty; j--) { 
                if (i > 0 && j < board[i].length - 1)
                    board[i][j] += board[i - 1][j] + board[i][j + 1];
                else if (i > 0)
                    board[i][j] += board[i - 1][j];
                else if (j < tablero[i].length - 1)
                    board[i][j] += board[i][j + 1];
        }
    }


    for(int j = starty + 1; j < endy; j++) {
            board[endx][j] = board[endx + 1][j] + 
                                  board[endx][j - 1];
    }

    for(int i = endx + 1; i < startx; i++) {
            board[i][endy] = board[i + 1][endy] + 
                board[i][endy - 1]);
    }

    board[endx][endy] = board[endx][endy - 1] + 
                                    board[endx + 1][endy]);


    return board[startx][starty];
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What paths are acceptable? Simple? Monotone (only to right and down)? Don't hesitate to give important details.

Comment: The only acceptable paths are top and right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you just start out with something like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0]
,[0,0,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,1,0,0,0]
,[0,0,1,1,1,0]
,[0,0,0,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

and then `M[i][j] = M[i-1][j] + M[i][j-1]` ?

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0]
,[0,0,1,3,6,0]
,[0,0,1,2,3,0]
,[0,0,1,1,1,0]
,[0,0,0,0,0,0]
,[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Yes, that was my solution at first, but I only placed 1 in (startx, starty), but then it looks like I got a bit confused. Thank you!